# Trigger command blocks remotely?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am currently working on a minigame, and I am trying to remotely trigger command blocks. Is there any way to use a lever and a command block to activate another command block 4K blocks away? For example, pull the lever and the farther command block will summon an enderdragon?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Summon a redstone block beside the command block:

```
setblock X Y Z redstone_block
```

I checked that it works even if the chunk is not loaded.

You can figure out the coordinates by standing right beside the command block, pressing <kbd>F3</kbd> and looking at "*Block:*"

May want to remove the redstone block afterwards so it can activate again later:

```
setblock X Y Z air
```

Comment: That's assuming said redstone block will then connect an activated redstone path though.

Comment: @Arperum why are you saying that ? The redstone block is self-sufficient to trigger it no?

Comment: @Shunwoo Oh, didn't know that. Learned something new today.

Comment: Could you also summon the ender dragon remotely or use an execute command? E.g. `/summon ender_dragon ~1000 ~ ~` or `/execute @p 1000 ~ ~ summon ender_dragon`?